# Why TableView makes NullPointerException?

Tags: javafx, tableview, javafx-8

I have this controller class for showing the data of the method "getProduct" in a TableView, but I have a NullPointerException related to "tableViewItem.setItems(itemData)". I read some posts about this topic but didn't solve the problem.

```
package configuradordepc.controller;

//All imports

public class ControladorView implements Initializable {

    @FXML private MenuItem mNew, mOpen, mSave, mPrint;

    @FXML
    private MenuItem mMother, mCPU, mRAM, mGPU, mHardDrive, mCase, mKey, mMouse,
                     mScreen, mSpeak, mMulti, mDVD, mFan, mPower;

    @FXML private Button bSearch, bAdd, bRemove, bClean;

    @FXML private TableView tableViewItem;
    @FXML private TableColumn<Product, String> nameItemColumn;
    @FXML private TableColumn<Product, Double> priceColumn;
    @FXML private TableColumn<Product, Integer> availableColumn;

    private ObservableList<Product> itemData;

    @FXML private TableView tableViewBudget;
    @FXML private TableColumn<Product, String> nameBudgetColumn;
    @FXML private TableColumn<Product, Double> outTaxColumn;
    @FXML private TableColumn<Product, Double> inTaxColumn;
    @FXML private TableColumn<Product, Integer> quantityColumn;

    private ObservableList<Product> budgetData;

    @FXML private TextField tFSearch, tFMin, tFMax;

    //Errors from TableView
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        //Items Table
        nameItemColumn.setCellValueFactory(
            new PropertyValueFactory<>("description"));
        priceColumn.setCellValueFactory(
            new PropertyValueFactory<>("price"));
        availableColumn.setCellValueFactory(
            new PropertyValueFactory<>("stock"));

        itemData = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        getProduct();
        tableViewItem.setItems(itemData);

        //Budget Table
        nameBudgetColumn.setCellValueFactory(
            new PropertyValueFactory<>("description"));
        inTaxColumn.setCellValueFactory(
            new PropertyValueFactory<>("price"));

        budgetData = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        tableViewBudget.setItems(budgetData);

        //Bindings Item
        final BooleanBinding noItemSelectedI = Bindings.isNull(
            tableViewItem.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty());
        final BooleanBinding emptySearch = Bindings.isEmpty(tFSearch.textProperty());

        //Bindings Budget
        final BooleanBinding noItemSelectedB = Bindings.isNull(
            tableViewBudget.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty());
        final BooleanBinding emptyBudget = Bindings.isEmpty(tableViewBudget.getItems());

        //Disable botones
        bSearch.disableProperty().bind(emptySearch);
        bAdd.disableProperty().bind(noItemSelectedI);
        bRemove.disableProperty().bind(noItemSelectedB);
        bClean.disableProperty().bind(emptyBudget);
    }

    @FXML
    private void onSearch(ActionEvent event) {

    }

    @FXML
    private void onAdd(ActionEvent event) {
        budgetData.add((Product) tableViewItem.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().getValue());
    }

    @FXML
    private void onDelete(ActionEvent event) {

    }

    @FXML
    private void onClean(ActionEvent event) {

    }

    //Item Table initialization
    public void getProduct() {
        //SPEAKER
        itemData.add(new Product("Logitech Z213 Multimedia Speakers 2.1", 22.95, 50, SPEAKER));
        //HDD
        itemData.add(new Product("Seagate Barracuda 7200.14 1TB SATA3", 46.95, 100, HDD));
        //HDD_SSD
        itemData.add(new Product("Samsung 850 Evo SSD Series 250GB SATA3", 82, 65, HDD_SSD));
        //POWER_SUPPLY
        itemData.add(new Product("Tacens Mars Gaming 700W", 42.75, 25, POWER_SUPPLY));
        //DVD_WRITER
        itemData.add(new Product("LG GH24NSD1 Grabadora DVD 24x Negra", 12.95, 55, DVD_WRITER));
        //RAM
        itemData.add(new Product("G.Skill Ripjaws X DDR3 1600 PC3-12800 8GB 2x4GB CL9", 37.95, 80, RAM));
        //SCREEN
        itemData.add(new Product("LG 22M47VQ-P 21.5 LED", 115, 10, SCREEN));
        //MULTIREADER
        itemData.add(new Product("Unotec Lector USB de tarjetas SD/MicroSD", 3.95, 110, MULTIREADER));
        //MOTHERBOARD
        itemData.add(new Product("Gigabyte GA-H81M-S2H", 49.95, 75, MOTHERBOARD));
        //CPU
        itemData.add(new Product("Intel Core i5-4460 3.2Ghz Box", 175, 490, CPU));
        //MOUSE
        itemData.add(new Product("Logitech Wireless Mouse M175 Negro", 12.95, 200, MOUSE));
        //GPU
        itemData.add(new Product("Gigabyte GeForce GTX 970 Gaming G1 WindForce OC 4GB GDDR5", 354, 480, GPU));
        //KEYBOARD
        itemData.add(new Product("Nox Krom Kombat Teclado + Ratón", 30.99, 54, KEYBOARD));
        //CASE
        itemData.add(new Product("NOX Sense 500W + Frontal", 41.95, 65, CASE));
        //FAN
        itemData.add(new Product("Cooler Master Hyper TX3 EVO CPU Cooler", 21.50, 220, FAN));
    }
}
```

Here is the output:

```
ant -f C:\\Users\\Marco\\Desktop\\ConfiguradorDePC jfxsa-run
init:
Deleting: C:\Users\Marco\Desktop\ConfiguradorDePC\build\built-jar.properties
deps-jar:
Updating property file: C:\Users\Marco\Desktop\ConfiguradorDePC\build\built-jar.properties
Compiling 2 source files to C:\Users\Marco\Desktop\ConfiguradorDePC\build\classes
Note: C:\Users\Marco\Desktop\ConfiguradorDePC\src\configuradordepc\controller\ControladorView.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
compile:
Deleting directory C:\Users\Marco\Desktop\ConfiguradorDePC\dist\lib
Copying 1 file to C:\Users\Marco\Desktop\ConfiguradorDePC\dist\lib
Detected JavaFX Ant API version 1.3
Launching <fx:jar> task from C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_71\jre\..\lib\ant-javafx.jar
Warning: From JDK7u25 the Codebase manifest attribute should be used to restrict JAR repurposing.
         Please set manifest.custom.codebase property to override the current default non-secure value '*'.
Launching <fx:deploy> task from C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_71\jre\..\lib\ant-javafx.jar
No base JDK. Package will use system JRE.
No base JDK. Package will use system JRE.
jfx-deployment-script:
jfx-deployment:
jar:
Copying 13 files to C:\Users\Marco\Desktop\ConfiguradorDePC\dist\run150788111
jfx-project-run:
Executing C:\Users\Marco\Desktop\ConfiguradorDePC\dist\run150788111\ConfiguradorDePC.jar using platform C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_71\jre/bin/java
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$155(LauncherImpl.java:182)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
file:/C:/Users/Marco/Desktop/ConfiguradorDePC/dist/run150788111/ConfiguradorDePC.jar!/configuradordepc/view/View.fxml

        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2601)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2579)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3214)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3175)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3148)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3124)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3104)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3097)
        at configuradordepc.ConfiguradorDePC.start(ConfiguradorDePC.java:15)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$162(LauncherImpl.java:863)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(PlatformImpl.java:326)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
        ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at configuradordepc.controller.ControladorView.initialize(ControladorView.java:75)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2548)
        ... 17 more
Exception running application configuradordepc.ConfiguradorDePC
Java Result: 1
Deleting directory C:\Users\Marco\Desktop\ConfiguradorDePC\dist\run150788111
jfxsa-run:
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 3 seconds)
```

The FXML file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

  <?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
  <?import javafx.scene.control.Accordion?>
  <?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
  <?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
  <?import javafx.scene.control.Menu?>
  <?import javafx.scene.control.MenuBar?>
  <?import javafx.scene.control.MenuButton?>
  <?import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem?>
  <?import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn?>
  <?import javafx.scene.control.TableView?>
  <?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
  <?import javafx.scene.control.TitledPane?>
  <?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
  <?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>

  <VBox maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.65" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="configuradordepc.controller.ControladorView">
     <children>
        <MenuBar>
           <menus>
              <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Archivo">
                 <items>
                    <MenuItem fx:id="mNew" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Nuevo" />
                    <MenuItem fx:id="mOpen" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Abrir" />
                    <MenuItem fx:id="mSave" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Guardar" />
                    <MenuItem fx:id="mPrint" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Imprimir" />
                 </items>
              </Menu>
           </menus>
        </MenuBar>
        <Accordion VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
           <panes>
              <TitledPane animated="false" text="Nuevo PC">
                 <content>
                    <VBox fx:id="vBox" spacing="10.0">
                       <children>
                          <HBox spacing="10.0">
                             <children>
                                <TextField fx:id="tFSearch" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS" />
                                <Button fx:id="bSearch" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#onSearch" text="Buscar" />
                             </children>
                          </HBox>
                          <HBox spacing="10.0" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
                             <children>
                                <VBox spacing="10.0">
                                   <children>
                                      <MenuButton maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Categoría">
                                         <items>
                                            <MenuItem fx:id="mMother" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Placas base" />
                                            <MenuItem fx:id="mCPU" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Procesadores" />
                                            <MenuItem fx:id="mRAM" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Memorias RAM" />
                                            <MenuItem fx:id="mGPU" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Tarjetas gráficas" />
                                            <MenuItem fx:id="mHardDrive" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Discos duros" />
                                            <MenuItem fx:id="mCase" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Torres" />
                                            <MenuItem fx:id="mKey" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Teclados" />
                                            <MenuItem fx:id="mMouse" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Ratones" />
                                            <MenuItem fx:id="mScreen" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Monitores" />
                                            <MenuItem fx:id="mSpeak" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Altavoces" />
                                            <MenuItem fx:id="mMulti" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Multilectores" />
                                            <MenuItem fx:id="mDVD" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Grabadoras" />
                                            <MenuItem fx:id="mFan" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Ventiladores" />
                                            <MenuItem fx:id="mPower" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Fuente de alimentación" />
                                         </items>
                                      </MenuButton>
                                      <HBox alignment="CENTER_LEFT">
                                         <children>
                                            <Label prefWidth="87.0" text="Disponibilidad" />
                                            <TextField fx:id="tFAvailable" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS" />
                                         </children>
                                      </HBox>
                                      <HBox alignment="CENTER_LEFT">
                                         <children>
                                            <Label prefWidth="87.0" text="Precio Mín." />
                                            <TextField fx:id="tFMin" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS" />
                                         </children>
                                      </HBox>
                                      <HBox alignment="CENTER_LEFT">
                                         <children>
                                            <Label prefWidth="87.0" text="Precio Máx." />
                                            <TextField fx:id="tFMax" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS" />
                                         </children>
                                      </HBox>
                                   </children>
                                </VBox>
                                <VBox alignment="CENTER" spacing="10.0" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS">
                                   <HBox.margin>
                                      <Insets />
                                   </HBox.margin>
                                   <children>
                                      <TableView VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
                                         <columns>
                                            <TableColumn fx:id="nameItemColumn" editable="false" prefWidth="75.0" sortable="false" text="Nombre" />
                                            <TableColumn fx:id="priceColumn" editable="false" prefWidth="75.0" sortable="false" text="Precio" />
                                            <TableColumn fx:id="availableColumn" editable="false" prefWidth="75.0" sortable="false" text="Disponibilidad" />
                                         </columns>
                                         <columnResizePolicy>
                                            <TableView fx:constant="CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY" />
                                         </columnResizePolicy>
                                      </TableView>
                                      <Button fx:id="bAdd" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#onAdd" text="Añadir" />
                                   </children>
                                </VBox>
                                <VBox spacing="10.0" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS">
                                   <children>
                                      <TableView VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
                                         <columns>
                                            <TableColumn fx:id="nameBudgetColumn" editable="false" prefWidth="75.0" sortable="false" text="Nombre" />
                                            <TableColumn fx:id="outTaxColumn" editable="false" prefWidth="75.0" sortable="false" text="Sin IVA" />
                                            <TableColumn fx:id="inTaxColumn" editable="false" prefWidth="75.0" sortable="false" text="Con IVA" />
                                            <TableColumn fx:id="quantityColumn" prefWidth="75.0" sortable="false" text="Cantidad" />
                                         </columns>
                                         <columnResizePolicy>
                                            <TableView fx:constant="CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY" />
                                         </columnResizePolicy>
                                      </TableView>
                                      <HBox alignment="CENTER" spacing="10.0">
                                         <children>
                                            <Button fx:id="bDelete" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#onDelete" text="Eliminar" />
                                            <Button fx:id="bClean" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#onClean" text="Limpiar" />
                                         </children>
                                      </HBox>
                                   </children>
                                </VBox>
                             </children>
                          </HBox>
                       </children>
                       <padding>
                          <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
                       </padding>
                    </VBox>
                 </content>
              </TitledPane>
              <TitledPane animated="false" text="Configuraciones" />
           </panes>
        </Accordion>
     </children>
  </VBox>
```

Comment: Presumably `tableViewItem` is null. Can you show the FMXL file?

Comment: @James_D I upload the FXML file in Google Drive, the link was in the post.

Comment: The link can't be accessed without permission. You should post the code into your question, though, instead of linking to it.

Comment: @James_D Sorry, the code was in the post.

Comment: Well, it wasn't, though it is since your edit.

Comment: @James_D *is, sorry I'm Spanish

Comment: Fair enough... :). You are missing some `fx:id`s in the FXML code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the `fx:id` attribute on the table. You need

```xml
<TableView fx:id="tableViewItem" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
```

(or just add the `fx:id` to the table in the "code" section of Scene Builder, if you are using Scene Builder).